# How to detect if executable requires UAC elevation (C# pref)

Tags: c#, windows, file, uac

how can I detect if executable requires UAC elevation? 
So far I came to two ideas: 
picture recognition of executable's icon to check if UAC shield icon is on it 
and information from wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

> it is possible to programmatically detect if an executable will require elevation by using CreateProcess() and setting the dwCreationFlags parameter to CREATE_SUSPENDED. If elevation is required, then ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED will be returned.[16] If elevation is not required, a success return code will be returned at which point you can use TerminateProcess() on the newly created, suspended process. This will not allow you to detect that an executable requires elevation if you are already executing in an elevated process.

Thanks

Comment: Note that the shield icon is superimposed over the executable's own icon by Windows Explorer, so actually extracting the icon out of the executable and examining it will not work.  (Also, that's probably not a good approach anyway...)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you give more context? You don't usually need to care if a progress requires elevation because the OS takes care of that for you. It's also near-impossible to catch all of the cases. (e.g. The process itself may launch without UAC and then, depending on command-line, manually elevate a COM object during startup. You can't tell if it will do that in advance without writing a CPU and Windows emulator :).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the CheckElevation function exported by kernel32.dll. This is a completely undocumented function, but here's what I've been able to reverse-engineer:

```
ULONG CheckElevation(
    __in PWSTR FileName,
    __inout PULONG Flags, // Have a ULONG set to 0, and pass a pointer to it
    __in_opt HANDLE TokenHandle, // Use NULL
    __out_opt PULONG Output1, // On output, is 2 or less.
    __out_opt PULONG Output2
    );
```

You'll have to do some experimentation to find out how to call the function properly. What I've been able to work out so far is that if Output1 is not 0, elevation is required.

Comment: It's not helpful to suggest undocumented functions which may no longer be available in future Win version, may change signature or change in behaviour. I would call this development by luck, not knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to use picture recognition if it can be checked programmatically? You can use P/invoke to call [CreateProcess](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateProcess) with desired parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to parse its PE format and then know whether its manifest file requires UAC.

http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2007/07/10/manifest-view-1-0.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+KennyKerr+(Kenny+Kerr)

Not sure how Kenny wrote the code, but it shows the possibility.

Comment: That doesn't cover all cases. Windows automatically requires elevation for installers without manifest too.

Comment: No public information available for you to know how UAC checks the installers. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx I guess you have read its "Installer Detection Technology" section. That's all Microsoft offers.

Comment: That and the disassembly of kernel32.dll :)