# Using the kernel32 CheckElevation function

Tags: c#, winapi, uac, kernel32

I'm trying to detect if executable requires UAC elevation so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154050/how-to-detect-if-executable-requires-uac-elevation-c-pref) question on SO. with the following answer

> Try using the CheckElevation function exported by kernel32.dll. This
>   is a completely undocumented function, but here's what I've been able
>   to reverse-engineer:
>
> ```
> ULONG CheckElevation(
>     __in PWSTR FileName,
>     __inout PULONG Flags, // Have a ULONG set to 0, and pass a pointer to it
>     __in_opt HANDLE TokenHandle, // Use NULL
>     __out_opt PULONG Output1, // On output, is 2 or less.
>     __out_opt PULONG Output2
>     );
> ```
>
> You'll have to do some experimentation to find out how to call the
>   function properly. What I've been able to work out so far is that if
>   Output1 is not 0, elevation is required.

So I created the following function

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint CheckElevation(
    string FileName,
    out uint Flags, 
    IntPtr TokenHandle, 
    out uint Output1, 
    out uint Output2
);
```

And I use it like this

```
uint flags = 0, output1 =0, output2 = 0;
            uint result = CheckElevation(path,
                out flags,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                out output1,
                out output2
            );
```

I tested it on some files.
On EXE files `result` = 123 or 2 and `output1` is always 0

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I can't find any documentation for this function, And I do not have much experience with the Windows API

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats wrong with the fully supported CreateProcess+CREATE_SUSPENDED->ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED approach?

Comment: But what happens with this approach if the executable doesn't need UAC ? I don't want to run the executable

Comment: Kill the process immediately. As described in your link. Do you know what "undocumented function" means? If so why are you looking for its documentation?

Comment: the result dependent from - are our process is elevated. if we running from already elevated process - `CreateProcess` will not return error, but successfully create process even if it require elevation (regedit for example). `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` can be only in case when we run this check from not elevated process

Comment: my process isn't elevated

Comment: And if UAC is turned off it will return false

Comment: *"I'm trying to detect if executable requires UAC elevation"* This question is missing the motivating *why*. In other words, this is very likely an XY problem, one that we could solve more easily if you explained exactly what you were trying to accomplish. Why does it matter if the executable requires UAC elevation? What specifically are you trying to accomplish?